# Good Representation of an angle between $0$ and $2\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently dealing with a angle vs. time type of graph, where the x-axis is the time instant and the y-axis is the corresponding angle expressed in radian.

I am adopting the $[0, 2\pi]$ convention here, which means the values are guaranteed to be within this range. The problem is that the $0$ and $2\pi$ are essentially the same and should be treated so in my application.

**I am looking for a good mapping** $f(\cdot)$ to represent the angle so that it is **a one-to-one matching everywhere except at $0$ and $2\pi$**, where$$f(0)=f(2\pi)$$

It is clear that a simple trigonometric function such as $sin(\cdot)$ will not do the trick. Although $sin(0)=sin(2\pi)$, $sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})$, which is undesirable.

Comment: If you want $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R$, there does not exist a continuous $f$ such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ is the only case of distinct $x$ and $y$ with $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer  So you mean it is impossible?

Comment: Yes, in the way you describe, if you want continuity.  Without continuity, you could take $f(x)=x$ when $0\leq x<2\pi$, $f(2\pi)=0$.  But for whatever you end up doing with your angles, won't you use trig functions that automatically treat $0$ and $2\pi$ (and $4\pi$, etc.) the same anyway?  If you allow vector or complex values, you could use $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$, or $f(x)=e^{ix}$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer  No... I will directly deal with the radian angles instead of doing trig functions to them. FYI, I am doing the Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) to the angles.

Comment: What do you ultimately need to do with the angles? Compare them? What you really have is a graph of a function $\mathbb R \to S^1$, which is a curve on a cylinder. From a brief look at the DTW wikipedia page it looks like you just need a notion of distance between two angles, which you can easily define.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Yes, compare them. Say in my DTW, $0$ and $2\pi$ are expected to have a distance of $0$.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng:  A possible distance between 2 angles $x$ and $y$ could be $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|+|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments I've ascertained that you really want to define a distance between two angles, which you can do easily. Two angles are just two points on the unit circle, so a natural distance is the smallest arclength/angle between them.

For any two distinct points $\theta_1, \theta_2$ on the circle there are exactly two arcs on the circle joining them. One of these arcs will cross the problematic point $\theta = 0$ and one will not. The one that does not has length $L = |\theta_1 - \theta_2|$, and thus the other has length $2 \pi - L$ (since they together form the full circle). Thus the distance on the circle between $\theta_1,\theta_2$ is just $$
\begin{align}
d(\theta_1,\theta_2) &= \min \{ |\theta_1 - \theta_2|, 2 \pi - |\theta_1 - \theta_2|\}\\
&= \cases{|\theta_1 - \theta_2| & if $|\theta_1 - \theta_2| \le \pi$ \\
2 \pi - |\theta_1 - \theta_2| & otherwise.}
\end{align}$$

This is the most natural metric on the set of angles so it should do the job; and it's also quite cheap to compute.

Comment: But this will cause $d(\theta_1, 0)=d(-\theta_1, 0)$, won't it?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: how is that an issue? Also, the above is assuming your angles are all in $[0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: Yes it is within $[0, 2\pi]$. Oh, sorry I should have said $d(\theta_1+\Delta \theta, \theta_1)=d(\theta_1-\Delta \theta, \theta_1)$. The issue is that instead of taking in the pairwise distances as arguments, my algorithm currently takes in the absolute angles as arguments. So I have to kinda find a common reference to express them all as the position on the unit circle, and then pass them to my current algorithm. So I don't want to map $\theta_1+\Delta \theta$ and $\theta_1-\Delta \theta$ to the same point. :)

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: then you're out of luck - you'll need to change the distance function used by the algorithm.

Comment: Considering my DTW purpose, what about this: I choose the 1st angle as a reference point on the unit circle, and then adopt your proposed method, express all the other angles in terms of the arc distance from the reference points (although θ1+Δθ and θ1−Δθ are now the same point by this method, it seems ok to DTW).

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: I'm not sure I understand. If the algorithm is comparing many different values with each other then there's no way to transform them such that the distance is $|x-y|$ - the answer you've gotten to your original question shows that in any attempt to do so there must be a discontinuity, i.e. there must be very close angles that are assigned a large distance after the transformation.

Comment: Ok, I see. How about this: I map $\theta$ to a point on unit circle $(cos\theta, sin\theta)$. Then, $d(\theta_1, \theta_2)=min\{arcLength\}$.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: that's what I described in my answer. If you're free to prescribe the distance function then it works.

Comment: I am sorry I keep rolling on this, but I still don't quite get your concern. Under what circumstances do you think it will fail? Thanks for the patience

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: Sorry, I think I misinterpreted your second comment. I was implicitly mapping the angle $\theta$ to $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ in my answer, I think you should be good. Note that you don't actually have to get the x and y coordinates involved at all - if you have angles in $[0,2 \pi]$ as your datasets then the distance function I gave will work directly.

Comment: Many thanks! Will go and implement it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand the challenge, we want $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is one-to-one on $[0,2\pi)$, and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.  If we require no further properties, one example is $f(x)=x$ for $0\leq x < 2\pi$, and $f(2\pi)=0$.  If we require that $f$ is continuous, then this is impossible.

Suppose that $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.  By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $x\in(0,\pi)$ such that $f(x)=\dfrac{f(0)+f(\pi)}{2}$, and there exists $y\in(\pi,2\pi)$ such that $f(y)=\dfrac{f(2\pi)+f(\pi)}{2}$.  Thus $x\neq y$, $\{x,y\}\cap\{0,2\pi\}=\varnothing$, and $f(x)=f(y)$.

More generally, continuous one-to-one functions from intervals in $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ must be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.